# Additional formula needed in IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sum

I currently have a large nested IF statement that uses a helper cell (C1) to dictate which formula to utilize based on numbers 1,2,3,5 & 6.  Specifically, one IF statement within the larger nested IF statement needs to be updated for instances when there is a blank cell in column A.  Here is how my workbook is setup:

1. Data Tab
   [image: Data Tab]
2. Bonus Tab
   [image]
3. Summary Tab

[image]

This is my current formula in Column B:

```
=IF(Data!$C$1=2,IF(SUM(Bonus!B2:C2)<1,0,1)*Data!$B$3+Data!$B$2)
```

What I am looking for is when cells in column A are blank, than the corresponding cell in Column B would be 0.  Again, the formula above has to remain in the =IF(Data!$C$1=2, format since it is part of a larger nested IF statement.

Answer I am seeking:

[image]

Thank you for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding an `IF` in there like this?

```
=IF(Data!$C$1=2,
      IF(LEN(Summary!A2)>0,1,0)*
     (IF(SUM(Bonus!B2:C2)<1,0,1)*Data!$B$3 + Data!$B$2))
```

or like this

```
=IF(Data!$C$1=2,
     IF(LEN(Summary!A2)>0,
         IF(SUM(Bonus!B2:C2)<1,0,1)*Data!$B$3 + Data!$B$,
         0))
```

Comment: I like the solution you provided, but the larger nested IF statement already has 7 IF statements including the =IF(Data!$C$2=2, which I believe is excel 2013's limit on IF functions.  I should have clarified that in the original post.

Comment: @Hery0502 Note that the first option I gave adds an `IF` but no extra levels of nesting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=IF(Summary!A2="",0,IF(Data!$C$1=2,IF(SUM(Bonus!B2:C2)<1,0,1)*Data!$B$3+Data!$B$2))
```

Comment: This solution works, but the larger nested IF statement already has 7 IF statements including the =IF(Data!$C$2=2, which I believe is excel 2013's limit on IF functions.  I should have clarified that in the original post.

Comment: @Hery0502 - why don't you update the question if you really need the problem to be solved. Please explain clearly what are you after now? Also post your complete formula and hopefully someone will help you out

Comment: @Hery0502 I believe that limit is changed to 64 levels starting from Excel 2007.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
=IF(AND($C$1=2,LEN(A2)>0),IF(SUM(Bonus!B2:C2)<1,0,1)*Data!$B$3+Data!$B$2)
```

I realise this gives you `FALSE` rather than `0` at the end, but I don't know what the rest of your 7 `IF` statements look like.

**EDIT**
Based on @AlexisOlson 's comment:

```
=1*IF(AND($C$1=2,LEN(A2)>0),IF(SUM(Bonus!B2:C2)<1,0,1)*Data!$B$3+Data!$B$2)
```

This now returns `0` when Column A is blank, as required.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, for the cells in Column A that are blank, the formula provides FALSE instead of 0.

Comment: @Hery0502 You can coerce a `FALSE` to be 0 in several ways: `--FALSE = 1*FALSE = FALSE + 0 = 0`.